# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php

Пишу данный код, но вместо его выполнения в браузере появляется такая штука Сайт выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз, подскажите как исправить?

```
function redirect_subdomen( $current_city, $arr ) {
    foreach($arr as $k => $v){
        if($k == $current_city){
            header("Location: http://".$v[0]);break;
        }
    }
}

if($arAuto["CITY_NAME"] == $usrSelCity){
    redirect_subdomen($arAuto["CITY_NAME"], $arrDate);
}
if($arAuto["CITY_NAME"] != $usrSelCity){
    redirect_subdomen($usrSelCity, $arrDate);
}
```

Comment: Для начала вопрос - в чем смысл двух условий в конце кода? И в том и в том случае выполняется один и тот же код, разве нет?

Comment: я исправил свой код, мне не понятно почему происходит зацикливание, несмотря на то что при совпадении я ставлю брейк

Comment: Можете еще лучше исправить, сделать не два `if`, а `if {} else {}`. Вообще же, посмотрите на свой код: `header("Location: http://".$v[0])` - вы всегда переходите по адресу, который содержится в элементе массива с индексом 0. верный код будет скорее такой: `header("Location: http://".$v[$k])`. Если я прав, дайте знать, оформлю этот комментарий как ответ к вашему вопросу, вы тогда сможете его принять.

Comment: `Смотрите у меня массив имеет такую структуру 
[Санкт-Петербург] => Array
        (
            [0] => spb.text.ru
        )

    [Брянск] => Array
        (
            [0] => bryansk.text.ru
        )`
Скорее всего ваш вариант не подойдёт

Comment: Действительно, структуру вашего массива стоило указать в самом вопросе. В таком случае вам подойдет такой код: `header("Location: http://".$v[$k][0])`

Comment: Попробуй не перекидывать заголовком, а просто выводить через echo ..., и ты поймешь что условие выполнилось - тебя перекинуло.

Comment: эх что-то не получается.... `header("Location: http://".$arr[$k][0]);` результат один и тот же

Comment: этот код у вас выполняется на всех сайтах? или только на главном? брейк то вас из цикла выведет конечно, но перебросит на, вероятно, этот же индекс, где опять сработает один из ифов и опять будет куда то редирект. отсюда и ошибка. То есть проблема в том, что у вас там как-нибудь по кругу редиректит с одного на другое. А не в том, что у вас в цикле несколько раз редирект делается. Откройте F12 вкладку сетевой активности в браузере, и увидите как у вас работают 301е запросы.

Comment: ваши if-ы в принципе делают одно и то же. результат всегда будет в пересылке на `usrSelCity` так что зачем вообще что-то сравнивать?

Comment: @Станислав там уж либо `$arr[$k][0]` либо `$v[0]` (как и было). а ваше `$v[$k][0]` это вообще нонсенс какой-то.

Comment: @teran, да, и правда, не прочитал более внимательно код. Тогда нужно смотреть, что там в $current_city оказывается, для начала.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом

```
if($_SESSION["CUSTON_CITY"] == NULL){
            foreach($arrDate as $k => $v){
                if($k == $arAuto["CITY_NAME"]){
                    $_SESSION["CUSTON_CITY"] = "1";
                    header("Location: http://".$v[0]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Только наверное CUSTOM ;)